# Downloading source code of Android Alarm Clock App

Tags: android, git, clock, alarm

Im trying to download the source code of original Android Alarm Clock via git but Im only getting errors:

```
git clone git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/development.git
Cloning into development...
android.git.kernel.org[0: 149.20.4.77]: errno=No error
fatal: unable to connect a socket (No error)
```

Any advices?
Is there any other way how to get to the code?

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523350/android-alarm-clock-ui

Answer (score 5, accepted):

github mirrors all the android projects. You can access the same repo from [git://github.com/android/platform_development.git](https://github.com/android/platform_development) .

Comment: Note that this is not an official mirror.

Comment: Hmm, ok I managed to download it, but I cannot find the source code for this Alarm Clock app there.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are following [the current instructions](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html), as the Git repositories moved following the kernel.org hack. [Here is a Google Group posting](http://groups.google.com/group/android-building/browse_thread/thread/23094426d1352ec2) discussing more about this.